# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. - React Hooks

Tags: react-hooks

I'm new to `React` hooks here, I've a sidebar I want to update the `selecetedIndex` to the index selected for that `ListItem` i.e., when I select an item I want to update `selectedIdx` to index to show it selected. I'm doing something wrong.

```
      <ListItem button key={index}
                selected={selectedIdx===index} // to show selected need to update
                onclick={setSelectedIdx(index)}
              >
                  <ListItemIcon>{v.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={v.text} />
      </ListItem>


 let [selectedIdx,setSelectedIdx]=React.useState(0);
```

This way second try I did but not results:

```
         <ListItem button key={index}
                        selected={selectedIdx===index}
                        onclick={handleSelectedIdx(index)}
                      >
                          <ListItemIcon>{v.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                          <ListItemText primary={v.text} />
         </ListItem>

function handleSelectedIdx(i){
    setSelectedIdx(i)}
```

I'm new I don't know how do we do `this.setState` in hooks. Both the ways it failed can anyone please let me know were I'm going wrong. Any help appreciated.

Updates: here I don't use:

```
{()=>{handleDrawerToggle}}
```

Still the following works why is that so? Can you please let us know?

```
<IconButton
        color="inherit"
        aria-label="Open drawer"
        edge="start"
        onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
        className={classes.menuButton}
      />

   function handleDrawerToggle() {
      setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);  }

  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem in you code is that you are not passing a function to onClick, rather a value returned by  `handleSelectedIdx/setSelectedIdx` and since you set a state a re-render is triggered causing the function to execute again on the next render. React internally prevents this loop and warns you.

The solution is to write your onclick like

```
onClick={() => handleSelectedIdx(index)}
```

or even

```
onClick={() => setSelectedIdx(index)}
```