# How to properly avoid error "Too many re-renders in reactjs"

Tags: reactjs

I used the code below to display records from **two** table successfully and its working fine

Here is my issue:

Now I need to display and hide a loading image or text as records is being loaded. I have added

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 setLoading(false);

  
let image_loading;
if (loading) {
image_loading = 'Data is being loaded'
}
```

in the return I have added the code below

```
<span>{image_loading}</span>
```

When I now run the script, it displays error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

The line of code that seems to cause this error is `setLoading(false);`. I have [a reference solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681024/too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-prevent-an-infinite-l) but it has to do with click event.

Here is the code:

```
import {initializeBlock, useBase, base, useRecords} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';



 function Rec() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const currentDate = new Date();

const base = useBase();

// get content of first table
 const tab1 = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
 // grab all the records from that table
 const records = useRecords(tab1);

// get content of second table
const tab2 = base.getTableByNameIfExists('mysecond_table');
 // grab all the records from that table
 const records2 = useRecords(tab2);

if(records2){
setLoading(false);

}

let image_loading;
if (loading) {
image_loading = 'Data is being loaded'
} 

     return (
<div>
    <span>{image_loading}</span>


<div>
<h1> First Records</h1>
             {records.map(record => {

                 return <li key={record.id}>{record.id} </li>


             })}
</div>


<div>
<h1> First Records</h1>
{records2.map(record2 => {

                 return <li key={record2.id}>{record2.id} </li>


             })}

 </div>

 </div>

     );
 }
  
export default Rec;
```

Comment: you are creating an infinite rendering loop by calling `setLoading(false);` in the body of the component - move all that inside `useEffect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you want to call setState or useState functions inside of a `useEffect`, with a condition.  The issue is here:

```js
if (records2) {
  setLoading(false);
}
```

By the time the code reaches here, `records2` does exist, and so it sets the state.  Once the state changes, the component re-renders, and this function is run again, and it goes on in an infinite loop.

You can use `useEffect` to make the running of `setLoading` conditional on some other variable.  Like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (records2){
    setLoading(false)
  }
}, [records2])
```

So now `setLoading` will only run when `records2` changes and if it exists.